# Issue with joined entity results: Undefined index: id in Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following code:

```
        $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
        $rsm->addEntityResult('App\MainBundle\Entity\InstagramShopPicture', 'p');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'id', 'id');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('p','lowresimageurl','lowresimageurl');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('p','medresimageurl','medresimageurl');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('p','highresimageurl','highresimageurl');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('p','caption','caption');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('p','numberoflikes','numberoflikes');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('p','numberofdislikes','numberofdislikes');
        $rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('App\MainBundle\Entity\InstagramShop', 's', 'p', 'shop');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'id', 'id');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'username', 'username');

        $query = $em->createNativeQuery('SELECT picture.id, picture.lowresimageurl, picture.medresimageurl, picture.highresimageurl, picture.caption, picture.numberoflikes, picture.numberofdislikes, shop.id AS shop_id , shop.username
                                        FROM App_instagram_picture_category category
                                        INNER JOIN App_instagram_shop_picture picture ON category.picture_id = picture.id
                                        INNER JOIN App_instagram_shop shop ON shop.id = picture.shop_id
                                        WHERE category.first_level_category_id = ?
                                        AND picture.deletedAt IS NULL
                                        AND shop.deletedAt IS NULL
                                        AND shop.isLocked = 0
                                        AND shop.expirydate IS NOT NULL 
                                        AND shop.expirydate >  ?
                                        AND shop.owner_id IS NOT NULL 
                                        GROUP BY shop.id
                                        LIMIT ?'

                                        , $rsm);

        $query->setParameter(1, 10);
        $query->setParameter(2, '2014-05-20');
        $query->setParameter(3, 10);
        $itemsFromDifferentShops = $query->getResult();
```

However I am constantly getting the following error/warning:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in /Users/Alex/Sites/App/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 2433
```

Here's what my entity looks like:

```
class InstagramShop
{
     /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
     *
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $username;


    /**
    * @Exclude()
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InstagramShopPicture", mappedBy="shop", cascade=  
     {"persist"})
    * @ORM\OrderBy({"createdtimestamp" = "DESC"})
    */
    protected $userPictures;

}

class InstagramShopPicture
{

      /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Exclude()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="InstagramShop", inversedBy="userPictures")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $shop;
}
```

Why is this? How do I fix it? My suspicion is because there are two id's. One is the product id and the other is the shop id, both having the same reference. But I tried changing it and it still gives me the warning.

Comment: `$rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'id', 'id');` it sit pointing to this line right?

Comment: @Viscocent I don't know, when I remove the addJoinedEntityResult and two lines below it, it works fine, i think the error has to do with $rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'id', 'id');

Comment: in your `InstagramShop` table, do you really have a field id?

Comment: @Viscocent I added my entity above for you to see

Comment: @adit I'd appreciate if you gave me the bounty if you consider my answer was valid for you, because if you don't give the bounty, only a half of the bounty will be assigned. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem some weeks ago, and I could solve it as below:

```
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult('MyBundle:Actor', 'a');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'id', 'id');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'name', 'name');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'surname', 'surname');
    $rsm->addMetaResult('a', 'presentation_id', 'presentation_id');

    $query = $em->createNativeQuery(
            'SELECT a.id, a.name, a.surname, a.presentation_id
             FROM actors AS a 
             INNER JOIN presentations AS p 
             WHERE p.id = a.presentation_id 
             AND p.finished = 0
             AND p.id IN (?)', $rsm);
    $query->setParameter(1, $presentations);

    $actors = $query->getResult();
```

Where there are some differences with your code, but perhaps you could adapt it in order to get what you want.

Note the addMetaResult() function which is used for foreign keys or discriminator columns.
You can read about this in chapter 17.3.5 of the official Doctrine documentation http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html. 
In this function, I pass presentation_id as parameter, which is the field for the foreign key of Presentation in the actors table. Note that I don't request information for the presentation, however, Doctrine hydrates the object and I can access to all the information of the presentation from the Actor entities of the result in this way:

```
    foreach($actors as $a){
        //
        // Some code here
        //

        $actorId        = $a->getId();
        $actorName      = $a->getName();
        $actorSurname   = $a->getSurname();
        $preTitle       = $a->getPresentation()->getTitle();
        $preDesc        = $a->getPresentation()->getDescription();
        $preDirector    = $a->getPresentation()->getDirector()->getFullName();

        //
        // Some code here
        //   
    }
```

I think that you could solve your problem in this way too. Maybe, you could do something like this:

```
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult('App\MainBundle\Entity\InstagramShopPicture', 'p');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'id', 'id');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('p','lowresimageurl','lowresimageurl');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('p','medresimageurl','medresimageurl');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('p','highresimageurl','highresimageurl');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('p','caption','caption');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('p','numberoflikes','numberoflikes');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('p','numberofdislikes','numberofdislikes');
    $rsm->addMetaResult('p', 'shop_id', 'shop_id');

    $query = $em->createNativeQuery('SELECT picture.id, picture.lowresimageurl, picture.medresimageurl, picture.highresimageurl, picture.caption, picture.numberoflikes, picture.numberofdislikes
            FROM App_instagram_picture_category AS category
            INNER JOIN App_instagram_shop_picture AS p ON category.picture_id = p.id
            INNER JOIN App_instagram_shop AS shop ON shop.id = p.shop_id
            WHERE category.first_level_category_id = ?
            AND p.deletedAt IS NULL
            AND shop.deletedAt IS NULL
            AND shop.isLocked = 0
            AND shop.expirydate IS NOT NULL 
            AND shop.expirydate >  ?
            AND shop.owner_id IS NOT NULL 
            GROUP BY shop.id
            LIMIT ?'

            , $rsm);

    $query->setParameter(1, 10);
    $query->setParameter(2, '2014-05-20');
    $query->setParameter(3, 10);
    $itemsFromDifferentShops = $query->getResult();
```

Thus, you would get the Pictures, and through these, you could get the information of Shops which you need.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with

```
$rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'id', 'id');
```

According to definition

```
/**
 * Adds a field result that is part of an entity result or joined entity result.
 *
 * @param string $alias The alias of the entity result or joined entity result.
 * @param string $columnName The name of the column in the SQL result set.
 * @param string $fieldName The name of the field on the (joined) entity.
 */
public function addFieldResult($alias, $columnName, $fieldName)
```

The second argument must be the name of the column in the `SQL result set` NOT `table`

```
shop.id AS shop_id
```

use `$rsm->addFieldResult('s', 'shop_id', 'id');`

Comment: I tried changing that, the error is gone however now I can't get the shop for the item. doing an item->getShop() returns null. I have tried adding shop.username into the select query